# How to shut down Rendering Problems warning in android studio?

Tags: android, android-studio

I have used some custom views that are from other's libraries and I have no access to the codes. When I tried to make a preview, android studio showed up an info window that saying `Rendering Problems` and recommended me to use `View.isInEditMode()`. I have read some similar questions and tried their answers, but all of them failed for me. Now I just want android studio not to show the exception info window again. Does anyone know how to shut down it in android studio?

Comment: just change your api level according to your sdk version

Comment: You have no control over it since it is from other library. In that case I would submit a bug report on that specific library support group aka the community and explain the issue.

Comment: I am using sdk version 24 and have already changed my api level to 24,but it didn't work.

Comment: It may take quite a long time for the specific library support group to fix the bug,and the warning is so disturbing.So I just want to shut it down before any useful solution.